# Reason to upgrade from ASP.NET MVC2 to MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, upgrade

With the release of ASP.NET MVC 3, I am wondering what are the major reasons (killer features) we should upgrade our app to MVC3.

Our app is currently in MVC2 using:

- Ninject & Ninject.Web for IoC,

  Linq to Sql

  jQuery (no ASP.NET Ajax)

  flot charts.

  MVC Contrib

  Custom REST (through dynamic WCF no XML config files)

We do not use ASP.NET charts or EF etc.

Is there any real compelling reason we should upgrade to ASP.NET MVC 3?

Comment: AFAIK there is no Ninject.MVC compatible with MVC 3, not sure, but check before moving

Comment: +1..because I am kinda interested in knowing the answers to this one !

Comment: @Miau, Ninject works fine for me after I upgraded to MVC 3.

Comment: @Kirk Woll - No matter how many times I hit that little arrow it will only let me upvote your comment once.

Comment: The MVC extension is available for Ninject, just not through NuGet yet. And Razor is worth it alone! Besides, it has been a very easy upgrade on the projects I've already converted.

Comment: If you choose to upgrade simply because of a view engine (Razor) you should check out Spark as an alternative. And you wouldn't even have to upgrade to MVC3 for it.

Comment: Ninject won't work in MVC3 under MEDIUM TRUST. I have investigated sufficiently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a few additional features in ASP.NET MVC 3

1. **[Razor view engine](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx)** (Widely seen as a vast improvement on the previous ASPX view engine)
2. Improved model validation with unobtrusive JavaScript and jQuery support. Including new [remote validation](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/01/04/ASPNETMVC3RemoteValidationTutorial.aspx) amoungst others
3. Partial page output caching.
4. Dependency Injection Improvements, new [IDependencyResolver`](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt5-idependencyresolver.html)

More imporvements and details can be found at [ASP.NET MVC site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3) along with [Scott Guthrie's anouncment](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/13/announcing-release-of-asp-net-mvc-3-iis-express-sql-ce-4-web-farm-framework-orchard-webmatrix.aspx)

But only you can evaluate whether you should upgrade or not for your specific project.

It should be noted (as Robert Koritnik commented) that MVC 3 requires .NET 4.

Comment: What about .net framework? Is it possible to run MVC 3 on .net 3.5 SP1 or is it bound to .net 4 only?

Comment: @Robert Unfortunately not, MVC 3 requires .NET 4 as it uses some of the updated features in .NET 4.

Comment: Exactly! I actually wanted you to put a disclaimer in your answer that even if you tick all the boxes and you're bound to .net 3.5, you'll have to stay on MVC2.

Comment: can you explain exactly which thing is improved in **Improved model validation with unobtrusive JavaScript and jQuery support** ?

Comment: can you please explain exactly which thing is improved in model validation with [tag:unobtrusive] [tag:JavaScript] and [tag:jQuery] support ?

Answer (score 4):

No more custom controller factory! This will apply to you. They wrote a new `IDependencyResolver` that you implement and `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(...)`. Your IoC will go through out the application.

http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/01/21/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-3-using-dependencyresolver-and-controlleractivator.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The main two reasons we're about to upgrade are:

1) The ability to control HTML validation on a per textbox basis rather than on a whole page- this means we can allow the users to enter HTML into some textboxes on a page, rather than having to control it at the page level.

2) Remote validation - much less ajax for us to write!

Answer (score 3):

1 **Razor**

2 Razor Intellisense within Visual Studio

3 Partial Page Output Caching

4 Validation and JavaScript/AJAX improvements

The Razor View Engine will make your view code nicer.

More details [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/09/announcing-the-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from all the answers there are few other reason for adopting MVC 3

1. Unobtrusive Javascript
2. Global Action Filters
3. Custom Validation attributes and Self validation