# Any resources comparing Rails 3 and asp.net MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, ruby-on-rails-3, asp.net-mvc-3

Are there any resources that compare the recently released (Jan 13, 2011) asp.net MVC 3 to Rails 3? I've looked around and couldn't find any comparisons but figure there must be something out there.

The last time I used asp.net was with MVC 1 and I'm wondering what sort of improvements they've made since then. I'm fairly new to rails so I'm not sure I can make a good comparison just by looking at asp.net MVC 3 itself. I'm hoping someone more familiar with the two frameworks has already made a comparison.

Sorry if this isn't the right place to ask but I do consider this a programming question.

**EDIT:**

I'd like to know specific comparisons between the frameworks. Advantages/disadvantages over using one over the other. View engines compared between the two. Static language vs dynamic language (if any comparisons apply). Ease of doing TDD/BDD between them. Features that are unique to each. Tools available, performance considerations, ease of use, etc.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971632/reason-to-upgrade-from-asp-net-mvc2-to-mvc3/4971700#4971700 to see some improvements that have been added in ASP.NET MVC 3

Comment: What kind of comparisons?  The names use different letters, is that what you are asking for?

Comment: @jfar Have you never seen comparisons between asp.net MVC and rails? Just google it and you'll find a ton (though none compare asp.net mvc 3 and rails 3). Anyway, I'll clarify my question.

Comment: @jfar If there's a better place to ask this questions I'd be happy the post the question there. But I've seen plenty of questions on stackoverflow about frameworks.

Comment: @ddd - Based on your edits you've asked for mostly subjective and argumentative answers. The only two bits that fall within good question territory are unique features and tooling.  Everything else is really based on how each programmer feels.  I don't like ActiveRecord patterns but that doesn't mean they are bad or wrong to use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP MVC vs Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090989/asp-mvc-vs-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: @marcind The link you posted has some good info but I am asking for differences specifically between the newest versions of asp.net and rails. I don't think either rails 3 or asp.net MVC 3 existed back then (about 8 months ago). Appreciate the link though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the lack of responses the answer is either "no" or "not yet".